# Identify non-unique rows, grouping any pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, running-count

I am trying to figure out a non-looping way to identify (auto-incrementing int would be ideal) the non-unique groups of rows (a group can contain 1 or more rows) **within** each TDateID, GroupID combination.

Here is an example DataFrame that looks like

| Index | Cents | SD_YF | TDateID | GroupID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 182.5 | 2.1 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 182.5 | 2.1 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 153.5 | 1.05 | 0 | 1 |
| 13 | 153.5 | 1.05 | 0 | 1 |
| 14 | 43 | 11 | 1 | 2 |
| 15 | 43 | 11 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 152 | 21 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 152 | 21 | 1 | 2 |

My ideal output would be:

| Index | Cents | SD_YF | TDateID | GroupID | UniID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 182.5 | 2.1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 11 | 182.5 | 2.1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 12 | 153.5 | 1.05 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 13 | 153.5 | 1.05 | 0 | 1 | 4 |
| 14 | 43 | 11 | 1 | 2 | **5** |
| 15 | 43 | 11 | 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 4 | 152 | 21 | 1 | 2 | **5** |
| 5 | 152 | 21 | 1 | 2 | 6 |

I have bolded #5 to draw attention to how index 14, 4 are paired together.  Similar with #6.  I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need to add the group number + the cumcount per duplicate + 1:

```
df['UniID'] = (df['GroupID']
 +df.groupby('GroupID').ngroup().add(1)
 +df.groupby(['GroupID', 'Cents', 'SD_YF']).cumcount()
)
```

output:

```
   Index  Cents  SD_YF  GroupID  UniID
0     10  182.5   2.10        0      1
1     11  182.5   2.10        0      2
2     12  153.5   1.05        1      3
3     13  153.5   1.05        1      4
4     14   43.0  11.00        2      5
5     15   43.0  11.00        2      6
6      4  152.0  21.00        2      5
7      5  152.0  21.00        2      6
```