# Pandas - Identify non-unique rows, grouping any pairs except in particular case

Tags: python, pandas

This is an extension to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72898485/pandas-identify-non-unique-rows-grouping-any-pairs).

I am trying to figure out a non-looping way to identify (auto-incrementing int would be ideal) the non-unique groups of rows (a group can contain 1 or more rows) **within** each TDateID, GroupID combination. **Except** I need it to ignore that paired grouping if all the rows have Structure = "s".

Here is an example DataFrame that looks like

| Index | Cents | Structure | SD_YF | TDateID | GroupID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 182.5 | s | 2.1 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 182.5 | s | 2.1 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 153.5 | s | 1.05 | 0 | 1 |
| 13 | 153.5 | s | 1.05 | 0 | 1 |
| 14 | 43 | p | 11 | 1 | 2 |
| 15 | 43 | p | 11 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 152 | s | 21 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 152 | s | 21 | 1 | 2 |
| 21 | 53 | s | 13 | 2 | 3 |
| 22 | 53 | s | 13 | 2 | 3 |
| 24 | 252 | s | 25 | 2 | 3 |
| 25 | 252 | s | 25 | 2 | 3 |

In pandas form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 4, 5, 21, 22, 24, 25],
 'Cents': [182.5,
  182.5,
  153.5,
  153.5,
  43.0,
  43.0,
  152.0,
  152.0,
  53.0,
  53.0,
  252.0,
  252.0],
 'Structure': ['s', 's', 's', 's', 'p', 'p', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's'],
 'SD_YF': [2.1,
  2.1,
  1.05,
  1.05,
  11.0,
  11.0,
  21.0,
  21.0,
  13.0,
  13.0,
  25.0,
  25.0],
 'TDateID': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 'GroupID': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]})
```

My ideal output would be:

| Index | Cents | Structure | SD_YF | TDateID | GroupID | UniID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 182.5 | s | 2.1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 11 | 182.5 | s | 2.1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 12 | 153.5 | s | 1.05 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 13 | 153.5 | s | 1.05 | 0 | 1 | 4 |
| 14 | 43 | p | 11 | 1 | 2 | **5** |
| 15 | 43 | p | 11 | 1 | 2 | **6** |
| 4 | 152 | s | 21 | 1 | 2 | **5** |
| 5 | 152 | s | 21 | 1 | 2 | **6** |
| 21 | 53 | s | 13 | 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 22 | 53 | s | 13 | 2 | 3 | 8 |
| 24 | 252 | s | 25 | 2 | 3 | 9 |
| 25 | 252 | s | 25 | 2 | 3 | 10 |

I have bolded #5 to draw attention to how index 14, 4 are paired together.  Similar with #6.  I hope that makes sense!

Using the following code worked great, except it would need to be adapted for the "Structure != "s" for all rows in the grouping" part.

```
df['UniID'] = (df['GroupID']
 +df.groupby('GroupID').ngroup().add(1)
 +df.groupby(['GroupID', 'Cents', 'SD_YF']).cumcount()
)
```

Comment: I don't get why in TDateID 2 we don't have 7,8,7,8 as UniID

Comment: sorry, because in this case all elements in column "Structure" = "s".  Whereas in TDateID = 1, we have pairs of "s" with "p".

Comment: Can you provide the input as DataFrame constructor?

Comment: sorry, what is that? / do you have an example

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` to be able to load the data easily (on my phone). `df.to_dict('list')` might help

Comment: updated the question.  Hopefully that does the trick

Comment: Btw, is the input always pairs of could you also have 3 or more repeats?

Comment: you could have 3+! Good question.  Those 3+ would all be unique to eachother though, just like in the pairs example above.

Answer (score 1):

Do the IDs need to be consecutive?

If the occurrence of "duplicate" rows is small, looping over just those groups might not be too bad.

First set an ID to all the pairs using the code you have (and add an indicator column that a row belongs in a group). Then select out all the rows in groups (using the indicator column) and iterate over the groups. If the group has all S, then reassign the IDs to be unique for each row.

Comment: I guess I was just hoping to avoid looping through a dataframe, but that might be one way to do it

Answer (score 1):

The tricky thing is to imagine how this should generalize. Here is my understanding: create a sequential count ignoring the `p`, then back fill those.

```
m = df['Structure'].eq('s')
df['UniID'] = m.cumsum()+(~m).cumsum().mask(m,0)
```

Output:

```
    Index  Cents Structure  SD_YF  TDateID  GroupID  UniID
0      10  182.5         s   2.10        0        0      1
1      11  182.5         s   2.10        0        0      2
2      12  153.5         s   1.05        0        1      3
3      13  153.5         s   1.05        0        1      4
4      14   43.0         p  11.00        1        2      5
5      15   43.0         p  11.00        1        2      6
6       4  152.0         s  21.00        1        2      5
7       5  152.0         s  21.00        1        2      6
8      21   53.0         s  13.00        2        3      7
9      22   53.0         s  13.00        2        3      8
10     24  252.0         s  25.00        2        3      9
11     25  252.0         s  25.00        2        3     10
```

Comment: I hear you - is there anything else that I can provide to help color the problem?

Comment: Give it a try, find counterexamples if it didn't behave as expected. Maybe next step tomorrow ;)

Comment: I just saw your last edit - does it complicate it if there are 3 possible types of "structure" variables?  "C", P", "S"  ?

Comment: hey mozway, I shot you a message on "Buy Me a Coffee" (wasn't sure if there was a better way) if you have a second